# angular 8.1 with ceisum Cannot set property 'Autolinker' of undefined

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

when i use angular new version 8.1.0

new project with : ng new ngx-map -enableIvy=true --style=scss,

then npm cesium . edit angular.json to import the cesium,

then cesium error with :

cesium.js:494 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Autolinker' of undefined
at cesium.js:494

when i use angular version 7 everything is right.
so, what's the problem??

Comment: https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/7981 -- Looks like you closed the issue, was this question resolved?

Comment: hi gays,i update angular version to 8.1.2 , this question solve